# Create an index variable that increments by 1 with each new value in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

How can I add an index variable to a data frame in R that increments by 1 with each new value? If I have a variable `var`, as in the example below, how can I create the variable `index` (preferably using tidyverse)?

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(  var = c(1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 6))
df
#> # A tibble: 6 x 1
#>     var
#>   <dbl>
#> 1     1
#> 2     1
#> 3     3
#> 4     4
#> 5     4
#> 6     6

desired_output <- tibble(
  var = c(1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 6),
  index = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4)
)
desired_output
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>     var index
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1
#> 2     1     1
#> 3     3     2
#> 4     4     3
#> 5     4     3
#> 6     6     4
```

Comment: `df %>% mutate(index = match(var, unique(var)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a factor and then convert it to numeric.

```r
df %>% mutate(index = as.integer(factor(var)))

#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>     var index
#>   <dbl> <int>
#> 1     1     1
#> 2     1     1
#> 3     3     2
#> 4     4     3
#> 5     4     3
#> 6     6     4
```